# How do I get the hidden achievement in the new Google Play Games app?

Tags: google-play-games, easter-egg

I've heard that there's a secret "easter egg" achievement in the new [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) app, how can I get that achievement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the main listing of games in the Google Play Games app, you need to swipe the old [Konami Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code):

**↑** Up, **↑** Up, **↓** Down, **↓** Down, **←** Left, **→** Right, **←** Left, **→** Right (and then when the retro button grid pops up), <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>▶ Start</kbd>.

[image: Konami code buttons]

You should then see an achievement notification pop up.

[image: Akk your game are belong to us achievement]

Here's a [YouTube video that demonstrates how to do this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pq1SWWMSW-M).

*via [Android Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/get-30-extra-lives-google-play-games-or-least-achivement)*